# Best practices of configuring repository in pom.xml vs settings.xml

Tags: maven-3

There are two different ways to [configure repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) in pom.xml or settings.xml.

What is the best practices, whether configuring repository in pom.xml or settings.xml?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to configure repositories only in settings.xml file furthermore it makes configuration simpler to use a repository manager.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But what if I published 4-5 jar modules which require different repositories. Now, as a client you are using these 4-5 jars as dependency. You need to configure all repositories in your settings.xml. Don't you? Wouldn't it be extra effort for you. Where this repository could be abstract from client.